# Windows Server 2008, Installing JBOSS 5.1.0.GA, Multiple services

Tags: windows-server-2008

When installing Multiple services, if I stop the second service, it brings down the first JBOSS service.  I am unable to get both services running separately on the same box.

Answer (score 0):

have you created a separate batch file for each service? have you changed all references to the lock files and directories this file references?

you can create a copy of service.bat and use this to install the second service, but there are several references to:

1. service.bat which must be updated with your chosen name
2. the lock file must be different, since each service will detect the other service's lock file otherwise
3. the directory paths must be different throughout the file.

Comment: any luck with this?